# Prove the distance between two sets in the domain of a continuous function with certain properties is greater than zero

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying for my qualifying exams by going through old exams and doing the problems. I normally can get somewhere on most of the problems but this one has me completely stumped and I don't even know where to begin.

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that:

1. there exist $x_0$, $x_1 \in \mathbb{R^n}$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$ and $f(x_1) = 1$
2. $\liminf_{\lvert x\rvert\rightarrow \infty} f(x)\geq 2$

Let $K_{\alpha} = \{x\in\mathbb{R^n} : f(x) \leq \alpha\}$}

A) Prove that for any $0 < \alpha <\beta<1$, $d(\partial K_{\beta}, K_{\alpha}) = \inf\{\lvert x-y\rvert: x\in K_{\alpha}, y\in\partial K_{\beta}\} > 0$. (Here $\partial K_{\beta}$ denotes the boundary of the set $K_{\beta}$}

B) Find an example of $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satsifying the first condition but with $d(\partial K_{\beta},K_{\alpha})=0$ for some $0<\alpha<\beta<1$.}

Comment: One place to start is: can you solve either part when $n=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint:

Claim: $K_\alpha$ is compact for any $\alpha<2$.

By continuity, $K_\alpha$ is closed, so it suffices to show that $K_\alpha$ is bounded. By (2), there is an $R>0$ such that $|x|>R$ implies $|f(x)-2|<2-\alpha$. Therefore $f(x)>\alpha$ whenever $|x|>R$, and so $K_\alpha\subset B_R(0)$.

Now fix $0<\alpha<\beta<1$. Suppose $d(\partial K_\beta, K_\alpha)=0$. As $K_\alpha$ is compact and $\partial K_\beta$ is closed, $(\partial K_\beta) \cap K_\alpha\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Gah thanks, I always forget about upper/lower semicontinuity

Comment: Does this finish the argument? I'm worried because I never use (1)
Let $x\in\partial K_{\beta} \cap K_{\alpha}$. Since $x\in K_{\alpha}$, $f(x) \leq \alpha$, but since $x\in\partial K_{\beta}$ every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point in $K_{\beta}^c$. So choose $\epsilon = \frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}$. Then for every $\delta$ we can choose a $y\in B_{\delta}(x)$ with $f(y) > \beta$. So $\lvert f(y) - f(x) \rvert = f(y) - f(x) > \beta - \alpha > \frac{\beta - \alpha}{2} = \epsilon$. So $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

Comment: I think I figured out how (1) is used. It gives us that $K_{\alpha}$ and $\partial K_{\beta}$ are non-empty.